# How do I make a url that is specific to some set of data with out a html file?

Tags: html, url

For example, facebook.  I have a list of different teams that shows overall data for that team, but the goal is the user will click on their team and send them to page that is detailed information about their team.  My client wants the user's team name to be within the url so they can save the page as a favorite.

How I do this with out making a html file for every single team that gets made?
Im using Django for back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using django then there is certainly no sense in making html for each team. You should make a template and populate this template with the data you're getting from your  database (models.py) according to url (urls.py) and the appropriate view (views.py).

This is fairly basic django usage covered extensivly in the offical tutorials and the django documentation. Read it and use it, cause there is no shortcut. And last but not the least - enjoy cause such good tutorials and docs you won't see every day.

Comment: I am not the one using django doing the backend, we are just doing this for volunteer. The best solution would be one that completely avoids the guy in the back.

Comment: If you already have django backend then it is the best way to do it because if you don't want to do it manually you'll have to automate html generation based on data, anyway